# Fhir on epic auth

Tags: c#

How can be authenticate the fhir api to get the response_code

"https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7066%2Fapi&client_id=7f9623df-0b06-432e-9516-c5c64e0ee9c9&state=abc123&aud=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7066%2Fapi",

Respose is
{
"version": "1.1",
"content": {
"headers": [
{
"key": "Content-Type",
"value": [
"text/html; charset=utf-8"
]
},
{
"key": "Content-Length",
"value": [
"906"
]
}
]
},
"statusCode": 200,
"reasonPhrase": "OK",
"headers": [
{
"key": "Cache-Control",
"value": [
"no-store, private"
]
},
{
"key": "Set-Cookie",
"value": [
"ASP.NET_SessionId=zkjxijoj0qx2hpihlncdxwpj; path=/Interconnect-fhir-oauth; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax"
]
},
{
"key": "Strict-Transport-Security",
"value": [
"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
]
},
{
"key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
"value": [
"origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with, prefer, Epic-User-ID, Epic-User-IDType, Epic-Client-ID, soapaction, Epic-MyChartUser-ID, Epic-MyChartUser-IDType"
]
},
{
"key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
"value": [
"GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS"
]
},
{
"key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
"value": [
"*"
]
},
{
"key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
"value": [
"true"
]
},
{
"key": "Date",
"value": [
"Wed, 15 Nov 2023 08:01:32 GMT"
]
}
],
"trailingHeaders": [],
"requestMessage": {
"version": "1.1",
"versionPolicy": 0,
"content": null,
"method": {
"method": "GET"
},
"requestUri": "https://fhir.epic.com:443/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7066%2Fapi&client_id=7f9623df-0b06-432e-9516-c5c64e0ee9c9&state=abc123&aud=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7066%2Fapi",
"headers": [
{
"key": "traceparent",
"value": [
"00-088fcdb5f74e334a9025849c88cdf901-a0e1bf5ccd78b1d9-00"
]
}
],
"properties": {},
"options": {}
},
"isSuccessStatusCode": true
}

having the issue in calling the fhir api and did not take the response